# Blender Freestyle in depth control

Tags: freestyle

How can I control specific edges I want to have an outline? I know you can make a freestyle edge mark and exclude them but there doesn't seem to be a way to edit it more in depth like choosing one edge to have an outline and another without in the same mesh object. I was just curious if someone has made an add on for blender freestyle that gives you more control like that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, this is native behavior. Freestyle edges can not only be excluded, they can also be included. And you can include ONLY freestyle edges if you so desire.
This setup does it. I removed all edge types but edge marks:

[image]

Comment: My question is can I include certain edge marks and exclude others for the same object?

Comment: I doubt it. Edge mark indicates the edge you want to be considered as an edge mark. If you don't want it drawn, you don't include it into edge marks. If you want all edge marks to not be drawn, untick the option in Freestyle.